# Fancybox content can not be loaded

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am getting the below message when using Fancybox. I have searched all the posts here and nothing seems to solve my problem. Please let me know if I am missing anything

```
"The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."
```

Input HTML:

```
<div class="ow_video_list_item ow_small">
   <a id="inline" href="#396">
      <img src="http://www.site.com/1.jpg">
   </a>
</div>

<div class="ow_video_list_item ow_small">
   <a id="inline" href="#397">
      <img src="http://www.site.com/2.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

Generated Output after transformed by jQuery:

```
<div class="ow_video_list_item ow_small">
   <div style="display: none;" id="#396">This is video 396</div>
   <a id="inline" href="#396">
      <img src="http://www.site.com/1.jpg">
   </a>
</div>

<div class="ow_video_list_item ow_small">
   <div style="display: none;" id="#397">This is video 397</div>
   <a id="inline" href="#397">
      <img src="http://www.site.com/2.jpg">
   </a>
</div>
```

Whenever I click the image, I get the fancybox popup saying that "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." based on which I understand that fancybox loads well as expected.

The jQuery to bind the Fancybox is provided below.

```
                   $("#inline").fancybox({
                       overlayShow: true,
                       frameWidth:640,
                       frameHeight:360
                   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **hash** `#` symbol when you refer (using `href` for instance) to a different element with an specific `ID` but such element doesn't need to have the **hash** symbol in its own `ID` attribute so

`id="#396"` should be `id="396"`

Additionally, `ID`s should be unique ... two or more element shouldn't use the same `ID`. If you want to use the same selector two or more times, use classes instead.

So change this

`<a id="inline" href="#396">` and `<a id="inline" href="#397">`

... to this

`<a class="inline" href="#396">` and `<a class="inline" href="#397">`

... and change your fancybox script to

```
$(".inline").fancybox()
```

Check the **[FAQ](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)** tab, No. 6 for more.

Comment: Wow.. you are the man... just solved my problem in a matter of second.. I just changed the <div style="display: none;" id="#396"> to <div style="display: none;" id="396"> and it started to work.